# How we can scroll down in email after click on a button

Tags: html, css, laravel, email-templates

I want to scroll down on `section_one` after clicking on an image.

My code is:-

```
<a href="#section_one">
    <img src="img.png" alt="">
</a>

<tr  style="margin-bottom: 40px;" id="section_one">
    <td>
        <table class="step1-section">
            <tr style="margin-bottom: 24px;">
                <td>
                    <p class="heading-2">Some text</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Also, Gmail changing my href to `href="#m_9152231230583106464_section_one"`

But it's not working. Kindly helps to find a solution. TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be `<a>` tag link for scrolling in email.
First `<a>`  has `href="#section_one"`. After clicking on this page will scroll and the second `<a>` has `name="section_one"` where the scroll will land.

```
<a href="#section_one">
        <img src="img.png" alt="">
    </a>

<tr  style="margin-bottom: 40px;">
    <td>
        <a href="#" name="section_one"></a>
        <table class="step1-section">
            <tr style="margin-bottom: 24px;">
                <td>
                    <p class="heading-2">Some text</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score -1):

Consider using a "div" element instead of a "tr" element for your section, as "div" is more commonly used for this purpose

```
<a href="#section_one">
    <img src="img.png" alt="">
</a>

<div style="margin-bottom: 40px;" id="section_one">
    <table class="step1-section">
        <tr style="margin-bottom: 24px;">
            <td>
                <p class="heading-2">Some text</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @mahesh. But there are two points-

1. Mail template can be set in table format.

2. Gmail changing that `href` to  href="#m_9152231230583106464_section_one"